# How to get a query of documents from Firebase, sorting by timestamps?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, users can upload documents to Cloud Firestore containing a timestamp. These documents make up a subcollection in the user's document, tracking their day by day statistics in the app. I want to be able to retrieve a query of these documents from the database, using something like `collection.orderBy`.

I'd ideally like to sort between multiple different time frames though. For example, I'd like to be able to sort through all of the documents whose timestamps match July 16th. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [range query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) with the timestamp field.  You will have to provide the start and end points for the query.

```
firestore
    .collection("your-collection")
    .whereGreaterThan("timestamp", start)
    .whereLessThan("timestamp", end)
    .orderBy("timestamp")
```

`timestamp` is the name of your timestamp field.  `start` and `end` must be Date or Timestamp objects.  If the period of time is just one day, then you will need to build start and end around that day.  In your specific case, perhaps midnight July 16 and midnight July 17 might make a good boundary, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you Doug! Prior to your response, I was trying to say stuff like ```.whereGreaterThan("timestamp")``` and then some date converted into a long, or I'd try something like ```.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", "July")```. Thanks for clarifying this for me (and allowing me to finally rest)